# не работает ng-model

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-show="discount.discount.days_details.monday.enable"
     class="add-time-block"
     ng-class="showInterval">
    <button ng-click="discount.addInterval('monday', start_m, end_m);"
            class="edit blue">{{::discount.lc.b_add_period}}
    </button>
    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
        <input type="time" placeholder="hrs:mins" ng-model="start_m"
               value="00:00"
               pattern="^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$"
               class="timepicker-rest-from">
        <strong>-</strong>
        <input type="time" placeholder="hrs:mins" ng-model="end_m" value="00:00"
               pattern="^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$"
               class="timepicker-rest-to">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span ng-repeat="interval in discount.discount.days_details.monday.intervals">{{::interval.from}} - {{::interval.to}}<br></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Суть заключается в том что я использую `angular-bootstrap-datepicker` и только версия `angular` `1.3.5` с ним совместима, но из-за этого не работает корректно `ng-model`. В результате `start_m` и `start_end` будут `undefined`.
Сменить datepicker на другой я не могу, так на сайте все по верстке.
А вот если поставить angular выше `1.3.5`, например, `1.4.9`, то будет такая ошибка

```
Controller 'select', required by directive 'ngOptions', can't be found!
```

```
<div id="datepicker0" ng-datepicker 
    dp-options="discount.datepickersOptions.from"
    ng-model="discount.discount_dates.from"></div>
```

Как можно решить эту проблему ?

Приложу ссылку на [ng-bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/cletourneau/angular-bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: можешь сделать **минимальный** пример, который можно запустить и увидеть ошибку про которую ты говоришь?

Comment: и еще добавь ссылку на компонент _ng-bootstrap-datepicker_ который ты используешь

Comment: хм, а на каком элементе у тебя стоит атрибут `ng-datepicker`? что-то в разметке в вопросе найти не могу

Comment: добавил шаблон для datepicker

Comment: а предыдущая разметка тогда чья?

Comment: `А вот если поставить angular выше 1.3.5, например, 1.4.9` в 1.4 добавилась директива `ngOptions`, которая добавляет элементы в селект, поэтому код данного контрола становится невалиден, так как, атрибут ngOptions теперь рассматривается в виде директивы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение этого вопроса такое и я считаю что не очень правильное, но это решает проблему:
Идем у `angular-bootstrap-datepicker`
в директиве `ngDatepicker` меняем у `scope` `ngOptions` на `dpOptions`. И еще там где используется `ngOptions`

Comment: так _ng-bootstrap-datepicker_ или _angular-bootstrap-datepicker_?

Comment: ссылку лучше в вопрос перенеси

Comment: angular-bootstrap-datepicker - попутал название модуля с названием компонента

Comment: похоже что ты не решил проблему, а просто убрал опции и теперь они дефолтные просто используются, а не те, которые ты задашь

Comment: Так я ж теперь буду использовать dp-options как директиву  и буду передавать те-же самые параметры

Comment: ааа, я не понял ответ значит :-) подумал ты просто в самой разметке хотел поменять, а ты в исходниках имел ввиду

Answer (score -1):

Используйте в качестве `ng-model` не единичный параметр, а объект вида `date = {start_m : '', end_m: ''}` и в шаблоне `ng-model = "date.start_m"`.